# How do I pass a multistring variable into php through a parameter

Tags: php, android, parameters

How do I send in a "multi"-string variable(looking like this: 1,2.3,4) into a php through a parameter which goes through an url.

Lets say some of the php that is connected to the mysql server looks something like this

```
`$id_ = $_GET['id'];`
`$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM brain WHERE braincell_id in ('$id_');`
```

And the variable that goes into it is: id = 1,2,3,4

How can I make this work?

What I am using currently and that does work:

`$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM brain WHERE braincell_id in ("$_GET['id']");`

EDIT.
Sorry it's me being stupid, it is way to late for me to be doing this stuff..... I missed a parentheses please remove this post.

Comment: BTW: Welcome your code the world of SQLInjection...

Comment: How can I avoid SQLInjections??

Answer (score 0):

Pass `$q`, your result resource. It references all the data returned from MySQL, and you can use the usual `mysql_*` functions on it (eg. `mysql_fetch_array()`).

Alternatively, call `mysql_fetch_array()` (or similar) and pass the resultant array to your function.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I know that will work out of the box is to pass each element of array as an separate parameter.

Here is my example:

get.php:

```
    $arr = $_GET['id'];

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($arr as $id)
    {
        echo "<li>{$id}</li>";
    }
    echo '</ul>';
```

URL:

```
get.php?id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3
```

Also you can pass key for each element:

```
get.php?id[0]=1&id[1]=2&id[2]=3
```